# Back from activity as deep link navigation destination

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have single navigation graph that has activity A as one of possible destinations. User is normally getting there (case1) like this `someView.findNavController().navigate(ZZZ.actionBBB(someParam))`. When user backs from A, all is good and well (say, if hosting screen had ViewPager and user was on N'th tab, user will see N'th tab). The same activity A can be reached via deep link (case2). When user backs from A in such case, app exits.

I'd like to have parent activity shown instead. To be more specific:

1. For case1, I'd like the behavior to be as described in case 1
2. For case2 (assuming app is not running), I'd like A exiting into new parent activity
3. For case2 (assuming app is running), I'd like A exiting into existing parent activity

Any ideas how to do that without hacking?

UPDATE: ended with this (not real solution though) :

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val upIntent: Intent? = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this)

        checkNotNull(upIntent) { "No parent activity intent" }

        TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
            .startActivities()

        finish()
    }
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269588/android-deep-linking-back-stack

Comment: @DerekK thanks I ended with something similar (updated my question) but it only partially solves my issue. I think I have to migrate to single activity solution to have full resolution.